# Thoughts/advice on cantilevered desk leg supports

Tags: furniture, legs

I am considering a "C" shaped leg/support approach to a standard sized desk I am planning. It's effectively a cantilevered design.  Something like this (but bigger):

[image: https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_bccc18f2-6fe2-4beb-b507-b78d6d0595b2?wid=325&hei=325&qlt=80&fmt=pjpeg]

I don't think I'll include front horizontal cross pieces in design, but might add to back.

These types of supports are usually made from metal tubes mitered & welded together, e.g. as pictured, but I'd like to keep this all wood.  If I do, I can see the joints experiencing a little more stress than maybe can handle, although desk only holds a hutch at back (over most supported area), a tower computer also toward the back but along one side, and a keyboard toward front.  So not front loaded with weight at all, except for actual table top, which will be about 30 inches deep.

I'd likely miter the two joints per leg unit for appearances' sake.  So, some design choices to help with strength and support seem obvious: add (actual) splines to joints; include triangle brace pieces to inside 90° corners; choose a wider rather than narrower leg design to increase the surface area of the joint; add another leg unit (or two).

Also, I think fitting a 4th piece diagonally from the top front into the inside of bottom corner of each leg unit would also obviously add support as well as look OK/interesting.

Any other thoughts or comments?

Comment: This kind of thing is totally doable in all wood, but you want to overbuild the heck out of it. *"So not front loaded with weight at all"* As covered in a lot of previous Answers, you don't want to build for the static, best-case scenario, you have to build for the what-if situation — even as simple as a person just leaning against it, much less if someone were to actually *sit* on the edge. Wood choice is going to matter; not just species but grain flow and presence of knots (ideally none) in all the critical pieces.

Comment: FWIW I trust well-made glue joints implicitly, but I would definitely not go with mitres on any of the load bearing joints, reinforced with real splines or dowels (or screws for that matter). You really want mechanical interlock without any inherent weakness for the core joint here (e.g. finger joints), *unless* the reinforcement is so OTT that it practically renders that joint irrelevant, as could be the case with a triangular truss plate if strong enough and connected well enough.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, @Graphus...here where I live there is a place that sells these which, while a tad pricey, certainly seem fit-for-purpose: https://www.rockler.com/rockler-45-deg-lock-miter-router-bits-1-2-in-shank.  I doubt adding splines or keys joints made like this would add much additional support or strength...maybe just the opposite!

Comment: An example sketch of what you're proposing would allow for a critique of the design. Otherwise, you're asking us to design it for you and that makes this question rather broad. Please feel free to [edit] in anything from a rough, hand-drawn sketch to a nice CAD drawing screen capture. Including measurements would be very helpful to ensure we understand the scale involved. Also, I agree 100% with @Graphus on this: Design to support your weight if you trip over the dog and grab the desk for support instead of falling, instead of just your keyboard & a cup of coffee. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Lock-mitre joints are strong structural joints for things like picture frames and small boxes, maybe drawers. Not for something like *the* joint for a cantilevered table; strength of a different order of magnitude is required if you want to be sure you won't get a failure should something unexpected happen. (BTW if you bought a bit like that directly from a Chinese retailer you could cut that price by more than 90%! If you want to buy a name brand, American-made, and are willing to pay for it, consider Whiteside which I think is the brand that Stumpy Nubs still recommends.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People (including aspiring, and occasionally experienced, woodworkers) can look at this sort of thing and assume the rear joints<sup>1</sup> just can't take the stress, but you can actually make *chairs* with this basic design if you build them right.

> although desk only holds a hutch at back (over most supported area), a tower computer also toward the back but along one side, and a keyboard toward front. So not front loaded with weight at all, except for actual table top

There's an important additional weight you aren't factoring in and that's the weight of your arms when the desk is in use. Unless you sit in such a way that your fingers perch above the keyboard and don't press upon the desktop *at all* the amount of pressure exerted by your arms is significant enough that you don't want to ignore it<sup>2</sup>.

And if you intend to write on the desk occasionally a good portion of the weight of your torso will press upon the desktop without you realising it..... and far more towards the front edge than the centre.

Plus, as covered in the Comments, for safety you *have to* overbuild for the accidental or unthinking overloading situation — someone tripping and putting a hand on the edge of the desk to steady themselves, leaning against it, or worse, actually sitting on it.

**So how to build it right**
Two options are using bridle joints (open mortise-and-tenon joints) or finger joints.

For additional strength and to future-proof it you should probably lock the joint with pegs. Additional reinforcement may make the pegs redundant but they look good and don't take much time to do so I'd personally add them anyway.

Since you've indicated you're open to using external fixturing (e.g. truss plates) or a diagonal support of some kind by all means add something. They'll add so much to the overall strength and stiffness. Have a look at the various iterations of the ZigZag Chair designed by Gerrit Rietveld to get other ideas of how you might reinforce the joints.

You haven't mentioned what wood you intend or hope to use here so a word about that is in order. If you're using hardwood you can use thinner stock than softwood, *much* thinner for the stronger hardwoods; as a very rough indicator, with oak you can use stock half the dimensions of pine, for equivalent strength.

Be selective in the pieces you use. You don't want any knots or significant grain runout (grain that angles sharply across) on the vertical members in particular. As much as possible these pieces should be straight-grained and free from defects.

> I don't think I'll include front horizontal cross pieces in design, but might add to back.

Yes I don't think this adds anything of structural necessity, unless the top is fair thin and the legs are spaced widely apart.

> choose a wider rather than narrower leg design to increase the surface area of the joint

The surface area of the joint is an important consideration, but bear in mind the axis of the strain. If you used e.g. 1"x3" (25mm x 76mm) stock you maximise the beam strength if they are edge-on to the sitter and desktop compared to the opposite. If you prefer the flat look you might want to go quite wide, and/or consider adding a third leg.

---

<sup>1</sup> From responses I've read most seem to focus on the top-rear joint as the one that will experience the most stress. But I think you have works out to 60:40 top to bottom you still don't want to skimp on the bottom joint. And if you're using power tools to create the joinery you actually save time doing the two joints the same because there's no additional setup time.

<sup>2</sup> You only tend to notice this when you use something like a cheesy flatpack computer desk with a pull-out keyboard tray! If you haven't ever used one of those believe me, you want to factor that in.

Comment: Thanks for all of this.  Your comment re: mortise/tenon reminded me that I have access to a Festool Domino joiner...will definitely be considering as I think about how I will be proceeding.

Comment: Honestly, I'd think that someone sitting on the edge of the desk would _probably_ be less load than someone tripping and catching himself on the edge. _Most_ people will sit at least _somewhat_ gently (unlike my dog who usually just flops on the ground), but when you're falling, you grab anything you can to keep your face from hitting the floor. Your weight is already moving, possibly quite quickly, and you're putting the majority of it on whatever will hold you up. There's a large dynamic load involved when someone is falling.

Comment: @FreeMan, agreed, a trip-and-catch could quite easily be a destructive load if the build isn't up to it. I'm thinking of getting some merch printed up, wanna be first in line for the "Overbuild the heck out of it!" T-shirt or hoodie? The mugs are cheaper but currently the lead times for ceramics are ridiculous :-D